# System.NullReferenceException при добавлении элемента в Коллекцию

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, коллекции

Есть код:

```
 public List<BrunchViewModel> GetBrunches()
    {
        BrunchViewModel brunchViewModel = new BrunchViewModel();
        List<BrunchViewModel> list = new List<BrunchViewModel>();


        IEnumerable<BrunchDto> brunchList;
        HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.GetAsync("Brunch").Result;
        brunchList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<BrunchDto>>().Result;

        foreach (var brunch in brunchList)
        {
           BrunchViewModel mappedBrunch = Mapper.MapBrunch(brunch);
            foreach (var item in brunch.OrdersId)
            {
               OrdersViewModel order = OrderLoader.GetOrder(item);
                mappedBrunch.Orders.Add(order);
            }

            list.Add(mappedBrunch);
        }

        return list;

    }
```

Модель (BrunchViewModel):

```
 public class BrunchViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }       
    public  List<OrderViewModel> Orders { get; set; }       
    //public  List<StaffViewModel> Staff { get; set; }
}
```

Модель (OrderViewModel):

```
 public class OrderViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Staff_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Brunch_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Client_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Gift_id { get; set; }

    public BrunchViewModel Brunch { get; set; }
    public ClientViewModel Client { get; set; }
    public GiftsViewModel Gifts { get; set; }
    public StaffViewModel Staff { get; set; }
}
```

Строка ошибки:

```
 mappedBrunch.Orders.Add(order);
```

  order имеет тип-OrderViewModel

mappedBrunch.Orders имеет тип `List<OrderViewModel>`

Текст ошибки :System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
DTOLibrary.BrunchViewModel.Orders.get вернул null

Answer (score 2):

Коллекция не проинициализированна. 
Сделайте это в конструкторе или обработайте данную данную ситуацию в маппере.

```
public class BrunchViewModel
{
    public BrunchViewModel()
    {
        this.Orders = new List<OrderViewModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }       
    public  List<OrderViewModel> Orders { get; set; }       
    //public  List<StaffViewModel> Staff { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, больше=)